# How to dismiss or unwind a view in Swift (Xcode 6)?

Tags: xcode, swift, segue

I have been scouring the web for the best and most proper way to dismiss/unwind a view using Swift and cannot find a definitive answer. For ease of concept, I have two views and have linked one to the other with a button and a segue using "show." How do I return to the original view (no data needs to be passed)?

Comment: Are you using storyboard and segues?

Comment: Did you make an unwind segue? Do you know what an unwind segue is? [Note that this has _nothing_ to do with Swift.]

Comment: I am using storyboard and segues, yes. And I do know what an unwind segue is but have tried putting it in my destination view controller with no success thus far.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding a button action to your `ViewController2` and add in the code below. Your `ViewController2` will dismiss when the button is being pressed.

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```